# Swiper in react lazy loads all images at once

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js, react-swiper

why the npm library swiper version 10 used within a next.js 13.3 or above (now on 13.5) project, when I set the images to lazy load as for instance

```
<SwiperSlide>
    <img src="/images/1.png" loading="lazy" width="1200" height="800" alt="image" />
    <div className="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
</SwiperSlide>
<SwiperSlide>
    <img src="/images/2.png" loading="lazy" width="1200" height="800" alt="image" />
    <div className="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
</SwiperSlide>
...10 more
```

on 12 different slides, they all lazy load at once when reaching the slider instead of lazy load one by one when swiping the slider' slides?

my swiper initiation is:

```
        <Swiper
            ref={slides}
            effect={"cards"}
            grabCursor={true}
            modules={[Controller, EffectCards, Mousewheel]}
            lazy={true} //also tried ="true"
            loop={true}
            speed={600}
            direction="horizontal"
            mousewheel={{
                forceToAxis: true,
                invert: true,
                thresholdDelta: 6,
                sensitivity: .2
            }}
            edgeSwipeDetection="prevent"
            controller={{ control: controlledSwiper }}
            className={sectionInters ? `worksSwiper ${styles.worksSwiper} ${styles.visible}` : `worksSwiper ${styles.worksSwiper}`}
        >
```